# how to download base64 string as pdf in IE version 11 & same for mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to download base64 string as pdf in internet explorer browser version 11

```js
  var data = "Base 64 string";
                var fileName = "MyFile.pdf";
                //For IE using atob convert base64 encoded data to byte array
                if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                    debugger; // shows something wrong in downloading the file(error in downloading pdf)
                    var byteCharacters = atob(data);
                    var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                    var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
                } else {
                    debugger; // this code works for chrome(pdf downloaded successfully)
                       let a = document.createElement("a");
                       a.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + result.data.data;
                    a.download = "MyFile.pdf";
                       a.click();
                }
```

else part works fine for chrome browser,but not working for internet explorer browser(v11) i got the pop up to save file in IE but then i got error message file couldn't  be downloaded any help is appreciated

Comment: Firstly, you should be able to `var blob = new Blob([byteCharacters], { type: 'application/pdf' });` without the intermediate 5 lines of code after `var byteCharacters = atob(data);` ... secondly, your code won't work in firefox ... thirdly, your code for IE11 works fine

Comment: I'd recommend just using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) - because it just works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check following code it's working for IE 11 and other browsers.

```
 function downloadFile(pdfBase64, fileName) {
// IE doesn't allow using a blob object directly as link href
// instead it is necessary to use msSaveOrOpenBlob
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    var byteCharacters = atob(pdfBase64);
    var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    return;
}

// For Other Browsers
const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfBase64;
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = linkSource;
link.download = fileName;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.remove();

window.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
}, { once: true });}
```

Comment: Is there are reason, that you're using `document.body.appendChild(link);`? Because other browsers will also download the file, when you don't append the a element to the DOM.